# How do I make multiple http API requests in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, api, python-requests

I have a List of Strings with more than 5000 entries, and for each of then I have to do a HTTP request to the API.
But it's taking too long to perform the task. Are there another way to do it?
What I'm doing.

```
List<String> list = ['a', 'b', 'c', ...]//more the 5000 itens

await Future.forEach(list, (item) async {
    await download(item.key);
  });

Future<void> download(String key) async {
    http.Request request = http.Request(
      'GET',
      Uri.parse(
          'http://apiurl$key'));

response = await request.send();
```

Comment: Have you tried to spin up an isolate to do the task?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you modify the api? You could send the `List` in a single request, and `Get` a `List` of responses

Comment: Thanks for the answer but can you explain a little bi more.

Comment: Instead of using the url query string, you could send a body with Post method containing your keys list ['a', 'b', 'c', ...] in json, the server process each one of them and returns the data you need in a single request. But I don't know if that is an option for you, if you can work on the api, I think it's better option than making 5000 requests.